How can i define project configuration (gradle/maven) when using Qodana in CI/CD Pipeline in Gitlab?
When i run the default .gitlab-ci.yml for adding Qodana it get the following error:
Defines project configuration that will be used to open the project.

Values are IDs of project configurators, i.e. 'Gradle', 'Maven'.

com.intellij.ide.environment.impl.HeadlessEnvironmentService$MissingEnvironmentKeyException: Missing value for the environment key 'project.open.type'

Usage:

Defines project configuration that will be used to open the project.

Values are IDs of project configurators, i.e. 'Gradle', 'Maven'.

at com.intellij.ide.environment.impl.HeadlessEnvironmentService.getEnvironmentValue(HeadlessEnvironmentService.kt:22)

at com.intellij.ide.environment.impl.HeadlessEnvironmentService$getEnvironmentValue$1.invokeSuspend(HeadlessEnvironmentService.kt)

at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)

at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.DispatchedRunnable.run(DispatchedRunnable.kt:43)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(RwLockHolder.kt:204)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:830)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithEnabledImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:138)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:129)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1152)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:81)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:123)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:43)

at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)

at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)

at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:699)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$12(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runWithoutImplicitRead(RwLockHolder.kt:105)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:77)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:362)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:361)

at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:361)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1022)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1022)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(RwLockHolder.kt:209)

at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:830)

at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:398)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)

at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

 at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

I wasn't able to add the project type in any other way. Locally this configuration works fine. Even excluding everything apart from the /src folder didn't help.

To pass properties like this to Qodana, you can use the --property flag. E.g:
qodana --property=project.open.type=Maven

